# Getting sector number from inode or address_space mapping

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, ext4, disk, block-device

In am trying to understand how to calculate a sector number from an inode in the ext4 filesystem. Therefore, I am reading [ext4_mpage_readpages](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/fs/ext4/readpage.c#L98) function.

About the function:
During a read request, if the page is not found in the page cache, a new page is allocated and added to the page cache. After that, the above function is called to get the data from the disk and fill it in the page.

I know that the size of a page is 4096 bytes, and that blocks are of 512 bytes (therefore, a page consists of 8 blocks). From what I understood, the above function maps the block numbers to pages in [blocks[page_block]](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/fs/ext4/readpage.c#L112) at these places: [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/fs/ext4/readpage.c#L210) and [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/fs/ext4/readpage.c#L164). After mapping the blocks, the function allocates a bio, **[assigns the sector](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/fs/ext4/readpage.c#L258)** to read from, and calls the generic_make_request() to read the data from the disk.

I am getting confused in understanding how the above function calculates sector given an address_space mapping. Is there any other way to get a sector number from an inode in ext4 filesystem?

Comment: [This guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/index.html) explains the format, so you can make calculations. (Thanks @StephenKitt for link update). If you just want the result without doing all the work yourself, the `debugfs` utility can help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is running the command `filefrag -v /path/to/file` which can be run as a regular user (unlike `debugfs` which needs read access to the block device, typically only for root).  This will give you ext4 physical *block numbers* (typically 4096 bytes) relative to the start of the partition for the corresponding logical offset within the file.  You can also use `filefrag -v -k` for units of KiB or `filefrag -v -b1` for 1-byte "blocks".

```
$ filefrag -vb1 google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm 
Filesystem type is: ef53
File size of google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm is 57333190
     (57335808 blocks of 1 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0.. 8388607: 5872025600..5880414207: 8388608: 
   1:  8388608..16777215: 5897191424..5905580031: 8388608: 5880414208:
   2: 16777216..25165823: 6241124352..6249512959: 8388608: 5905580032:
   3: 25165824..33554431: 8019509248..8027897855: 8388608: 6249512960:
   4: 33554432..41943039: 8128561152..8136949759: 8388608: 8027897856:
   5: 41943040..50331647: 8220835840..8229224447: 8388608: 8136949760:
   6: 50331648..57335807: 28538081280..28545085439: 7004160: 8229224448: last,eof
```

This is using `ioctl(fd, FS_IOC_FIEMAP, ...)` to request the extent mapping for the file descriptor, which in turn uses the `->fiemap()` method of most common filesystems.  Much older kernels used `ioctl(fd, FS_IOC_FIBMAP, ...)` but it can only map a single block at a time, and may require millions of calls for large files today.